How to find and click on a button of a website?
I'm trying to develop a Python script based on Selenium to manipulate a website. Here is the website:
https://www.heatpumpkeymark.com/en/?type=109126&tx_pskeymark_frontend%5Bholder%5D=2482&tx_pskeymark_frontend%5Baction%5D=certificateHolder&tx_pskeymark_frontend%5Bcontroller%5D=Frontend&cHash=1f82e53f3d95d0b9ebfe0c7bb0cdfeb2
and I want to find and click on the button "Download reports for all subtypes". I successfully did this for other websites but not in that one.
My following scripts don't work.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

webdriver_path = r'D:\MyWork\driver\chromedriver.exe'

service = Service(webdriver_path)
chrome_options = Options()

url = "https://www.heatpumpkeymark.com/en/?type=109126&tx_pskeymark_frontend%5Bholder%5D=2482&tx_pskeymark_frontend%5Baction%5D=certificateHolder&tx_pskeymark_frontend%5Bcontroller%5D=Frontend&cHash=1f82e53f3d95d0b9ebfe0c7bb0cdfeb2"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)  

class_name = 'btn btn-primary'
text = 'Download reports for all subtypes'

try:
    # button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//button[class()="{class_name}"]')))
    button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//button[text()="{text}"]')))
    
    if button:
        print('Button found')
    else:
        print('Button not found')

finally:
    driver.quit()

When running the above script, the error is on the line "button = ...", as following:
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 29
     25 text = 'Download reports for all subtypes'
     27 try:
     28     # button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//button[class()="{class_name}"]')))
---> 29     button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//button[text()="{text}"]')))
     31     if button:
     32         print('Button found')

File c:\Users\ctran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:105, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
    103     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
    104         break
--> 105 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6268F22C2+60002]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF62686CA59]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF626727EDA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6267776E6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6267777AC]
...

Have you any idea on how to solve the problem? Thank you for your help.

Looks like your XPATH is not targeting any elements. //a[text()="Download reports for all subtypes"] XPATH targets the button that you want to click.

Not sur for understand your suggestion, but I have already defined text = 'Download reports for all subtypes'

Yes but you defined ‘ //button[text()’ that doesn’t exist so instead you should use ‘ //a[text()=’.

It seems like the Xpath is not reachable, I would want to just fix the XPath like this
(on line 29)
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')))

